# Using watchify with babelify

Tags: javascript, browserify, reactjs, babeljs

Is it practical to use watchify with babelify?

I'm trying out React and running a project in dev mode with:

```
watchify app/src/src.js -t babelify -o app/build/build.js
```

I expect watchify to look for changes on `src.js` and compile a functional `build.js` with all the required modules and use babelify to compile the jsx parts of the script.

But that seems to take a lot of time, and I end up with a 19000 lines build for my one line script:

```
var React = require('react');
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: React is installed from npm or is otherwise in `node_modules`, right? React is sizable and they do quite a bit of processing on it to get the size of their browser build down, which you don't automatically get when you `require()` / browserify it. If it's slow initially it should be much faster when you update a file and it rebuilds.

Comment: Yes but rebuilding is slow too, so I'll retrieve react from a script tag in my html file instead. Thanks

Comment: It sounds like something is out of whack with the process then. But loading React separately is definitely something to consider. You should still `require()` it in your app code rather than rely on an implicit global, and flag it as external / excluded for browserify.

Comment: Then, is it possible watchify with babelify as `watchify <source> -t babelify -o <output>`? Does watchify accept a transform flag?

Comment: ok, It does for for example `uglify`, but syntax is as follows, `watchify main.js -o 'uglifyjs -cm > static/bundle.min.js'`. Not sure if works with `babelify` too.

Comment: The syntax in my post worked fine for babelify

Answer (score 2):

That is correct. The [React](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.13.3/react.js) library is approximately 19000 lines long.

Browserify will bundle all your dependencies together.

If you don't need React then don't require it in.

Comment: Ok in that case I'll just retrieve the react library from a html script tag. Thanks